# Is it always true that $\operatorname{Mat}(L)^n = \operatorname{Mat}(L)\operatorname{Mat}(L)\cdots (n\text{ times}) = \operatorname{Mat}(L^n)$?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Is it always true for a matrix of a linear transformation that $$\operatorname{Mat}(L)^n = \operatorname{Mat}(L)\operatorname{Mat}(L) \cdots (n\text{ times}) = \operatorname{Mat}(L^n) \text{?}$$

---

$\operatorname{Mat}(L)$ is the equivalent matrix expression of a linear transformation $L$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

$L^n$ means $n$-times function composition of function $L$.

Comment: I think it might be better to say it is equal to $L\circ \cdots \circ L$, where $\circ$ denotes composition. Unless of course your notation $L^n$ is indeed shorthand for repeated composition.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Doesn't matrix multiplication equal function composition? This question also sort of concerns, whether it actually does.

Comment: It does. I was just taking a little issue with the notation $L^n$ since it is slightly ambiguous. Some people mean $f^n(x)$ to be $f(x)^n$; others mean $f^n(x)$ to be $(f\circ \cdots \circ f)(x)$. At any rate, $\operatorname{Mat}(L)^n = \operatorname{Mat}(L\circ\cdots\circ L)$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Given a basis, the map, which sends a linear map to the matrix w.r.t. this basis is a $K$-algebra isomorphism, in particular the claim in your question holds.

Of course its important, that we use only one basis and not two different bases (The identity map is idempotent, but a base change matrix of two bases, which is just the matrix of the identity map w.r.t. these bases, is not).